# link to div in a separate tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to link to a div that is in a separate tab. Currently the side navigation link is like this:

```
var loc = window.location.hash;
if (loc == "#bargain") {
    jQuery('.tab-2').click();
    App.SetBaseLine();
    jQuery('#bargain').addClass('activeListColor');
};

      <li><a href="default.aspx#bargain">Bargain Packages</a></li>

    <!-- start of tabHolder -->
    <div id="tabHolder">
        <ul class="tabs_new buttons">
            <li class="liOuter" id="tab1"><a href="#" class="current tab-1">Buyers' Guide</a></li>
            <li class="liInner" id="tab2"><a href="#" class="tab-2">Pricing Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Unfortunately, this does not take me under the second tab. I am trying to have a user click the link, and it opens the tab and anchors down to the div location.

I am open to suggestions.

Comment: By "tab", do you mean browser tab or a tab-like feature within a web page?

Comment: Which tab plugin are you using? Maybe there's a better way to switch than to fire a click event. Does the other tab load its content with Ajax?

Comment: Can you prepare a demo on Fiddle?

Comment: @maddev Can you check this: http://jsfiddle.net/U3KLs/1/

Comment: Like that, but I need a link on the side that if you click the link on tab1 and the link is supposed to go to a tab2 div, that the tabs transition and take you to content div location. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
<ul class="tab">
    <li><a href="#tab1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Three</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs">
    <div id="tab1">Content 1</div>
    <div id="tab2">Something here</div>
    <div id="tab3">Omg! Three</div>
</div>
```

And the **script** as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tab > li > a").click(function(){
        var tab = $(this).attr('href');
        $(".tab > li > a").removeAttr("style");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ccc");
        $('.tabs > div:visible').hide(function(){
            $(tab).show();
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('.tabs > div').hide();
    $('.tabs > div:first-child').show();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
body {overflow: hidden;}
ul li {display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1;}
a {text-decoration: none; color: #f60; border-radius: 5px; padding: 5px; display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1;}
div {padding: 5px;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3KLs/1/)! Hope this is a best way to use tabs. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jQuery to achieve a 'tab' like effect

```
​$('a').click(function() {
    $('div').hide();
    var destination = '#' + $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $(destination).toggle();
});​
```

See this [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/RCbgV/)

Here is an [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/RCbgV/1/) with the divs wrapped in an unordered list

Alternatively, you can use a 'current' class and toggle that on click using the following code:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('.tabs div').removeClass('current');
    var destination = '#' + $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $(destination).toggleClass('current');
});​
```

Another [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/RCbgV/2/) here

Comment: `data-` attribute support in IE 7 / IE 8?

Comment: Almost, but not quite. Maybe this will help clarify. jsfiddle.net/LB59Q

Comment: Not really :/ Can you be more specific? Surely you can adapt my code yourself, this isn't an end-to-end code valet service!

Comment: I have the tab functionality working. That is not a problem for me. What is the problem is lets say you are on the default.aspx page. On the default page I have a tab content area with 2 tabs. First is open, and you click the second tab to open it. I am trying to have it set up where I have a link on the side saying "bargain" and is linked to "default.aspx#bargain", but tab2 would need to automatically open in order to go to that div location.